# ScrollView not working inside constraint layout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, android-scrollview

I have a scrollview inside ConstraintLayout. but scrollview not working in ConstraintLayout. I tried NestedScrollView instead of ScrollView but it still not working. ScrollView worked fine with LinearLayout or RelativeLayout but in didn't work in ConstraintLayout.I changed android:layout_height to match_parent and wrap_content but it didn't work. what is the problem?

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    >

    <include
        android:id="@+id/other_toolbar_xml"
        layout="@layout/other_toolbar_xml"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/other_toolbar_xml"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        >

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_content_xml"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="170dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/other_toolbar_xml"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                tools:ignore="NotSibling"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title_content_xml"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/img_content_xml"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                android:textDirection="rtl"
                android:text="title"
                android:textSize="17sp"
                android:textColor="#1d1d1d"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/content_content_xml"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/title_content_xml"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                android:textDirection="rtl"
                android:text="content"
                android:textColor="#1d1d1d"
                />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_date_content_Xml"
                android:layout_width="18dp"
                android:layout_height="18dp"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/content_content_xml"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:src="@drawable/date"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/date_content_xml"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/content_content_xml"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/img_date_content_Xml"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:text="date"
                android:textColor="#1d1d1d"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/subject_content_xml"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/content_content_xml"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="subject"
                android:textColor="#1d1d1d"
                />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You missed some constraint to give as you have added `tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"` in `<ScrollView` tag.

There are two ways:

1. Remove Parent **Constraint Layout** and use **RelativeLayout** as no need of **ConstraintLayout** in just two layouts. (It is mostly used for complex view to make it easy)
2. Give proper constraint if you want to use **ConstraintLayout**. You missed left, right, bottom constraint as follow:

   ```
   <ScrollView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="0dp"
       android:fillViewport="true"        
       app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/other_toolbar_xml"
       app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" >

   //....

   </ScrollView>
   ```

Answer (score 3):

> Firstly if you are using `constraintlayout` as the parent layout so
>   you need to constrain child views properly.`Scrollview` that you have defined is not constrained properly that's why scrollview
>   doesn't work.

**Here is my code:**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/other_toolbar_xml"
        layout="@layout/toolbar_back"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/other_toolbar_xml"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_content_xml"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="170dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/other_toolbar_xml"
                tools:ignore="NotSibling" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title_content_xml"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                android:text="title"
                android:textColor="#1d1d1d"
                android:textDirection="rtl"
                android:textSize="17sp"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/img_content_xml" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/content_content_xml"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                android:text="content"
                android:textColor="#1d1d1d"
                android:textDirection="rtl"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/title_content_xml" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_date_content_Xml"
                android:layout_width="18dp"
                android:layout_height="18dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:src="@drawable/date"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/content_content_xml" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/date_content_xml"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:text="date"
                android:textColor="#1d1d1d"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/img_date_content_Xml"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/content_content_xml" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/subject_content_xml"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="subject"
                android:textColor="#1d1d1d"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/content_content_xml" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```